# Include special chars in a protobuf message in java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I want to include special chars like � and  in a protobuf message. Protobuf is converting them into \302\240 when building the message. Is there any way we can build the message with these chars. One option is to use bytes filed in the proto. I want to other options.

Example:

```
proto - 
message data {
string value = 1;
}

input - "foo�bar"
MESSAGE - 
data_msg {
value: "foo&#65533;bar"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ironically you express a desire to reproduce a character which is itself a *replacement char* and therefore indicative of an error. Does your message include Hangul chars you want to show?

Comment: @g00se No. it doesnt show.

Comment: You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `&#65533;` is a numerical character reference as used in HTML and XML. The Protobuf text format does not use that as far as I understand. So I'm *reasonably sure* that it's not the protobuf library that applies this transformation, but something else in your pipeline. If you can really provide the [mre] (including the Java code that produces the claimed output) then we can start investigating where things go wrong.

Comment: *Protobuf is converting them into \302\240 when building the message.* Also, there is possibly a misconception here: the whole purpose of Protobuf involves *converting* input for transport purposes, so if you're somehow trying to use its transport format to derive your input instead of using its decoding/desrialization mechanisms, then you're going to get problems

Answer (score 0):

&#65533; is an html encoding of your symbol � So it is OK to go with that. unicode for that symbol is 65533 or in hexadecimal - \ufffd You can also replace your string `"foo�bar"` with `"foo\ufffdbar"` and then convert it to protobuf - it will also work. Here is an on-line converter: https://checkserp.com/encode/unicode/ or more comprehensive one - https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/. Also, if you want to convert text to unicodes programmatically you can use MgntUtils Open source library written and maintained by me that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found as [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) with source code and Javadoc. Here is a [Javadoc for StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)